# Login personalizado en firebase con nombre de usuario y contraseña

Tags: nodejs, angular, firebase, ionic, firebase-auth

Quiero realizar un login personalizado en Firebase, (con NodeJs, Angular, Ionic), utilizando un nombre de usuario y una contraseña. Cómo se puede realizar esto? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? Adjunta tu código

Comment: Estoy buscando documentación, todo lo que encuentro es utilizando servicios de terceros (google, facebook, etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. importar en el appModule todas las librerias de Firebase

   ```
     @NgModule({
         declarations: [AppComponent],
         entryComponents: [],
         imports: [  
         AngularFireModule.initializeApp(INFOFIREBASE),
       AngularFirestoreModule,
       AngularFireDatabaseModule,
       AngularFireAuthModule
     ],
   ```
2. Usar la api de firebase

...

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

...

Documentación de fireBase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth?hl=es